# Why isn't fallthrough allowed in a type switch?

Tags: switch-statement, go

I'm wondering why fallthrough isn't allowed in a type switch statement in golang.

According to the [specification](http://golang.org/ref/spec): "The "fallthrough" statement is not permitted in a type switch.", which doesn't explain much about WHY it isn't allowed.

The code attached is to simulate a possible scenario were a fallthrough in a type switch statement might have been useful.

**Notice!** This code doesn't work, it will produce the error: "cannot fallthrough in type switch". I'm just wondering what possible reasons might have been for not allowing the fallthrough statement in a type switch.

```
//A type switch question
package main

import "fmt"

//Why isn't fallthrough in type switch allowed?
func main() {
    //Empty interface
    var x interface{}

    x = //A int, float64, bool or string value

    switch i := x.(type) {
    case int:
        fmt.Println(i + 1)
    case float64:
        fmt.Println(i + 2.0)
    case bool:
        fallthrough
    case string:
        fmt.Printf("%v", i)
    default:
        fmt.Println("Unknown type. Sorry!")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 51, accepted):

How would you expect `fallthrough` to work? In this type switch, the `i` variable has a type that depends on the particular case that's invoked. So in the `case bool` the `i` variable is typed as `bool`. But in `case string` it's typed as `string`. So either you're asking for `i` to magically morph its type, which isn't possible, or you're asking for it to be shadowed by a new variable `i string`, which will have no value because its value comes from `x` which is not, in fact, a `string`.

---

Here's an example to try and illustrate the problem:

```
switch i := x.(type) {
case int:
    // i is an int
    fmt.Printf("%T\n", i); // prints "int"
case bool:
    // i is a bool
    fmt.Printf("%T\n", i); // prints "bool"
    fallthrough
case string:
    fmt.Printf("%T\n", i);
    // What does that type? It should type "string", but if
    // the type was bool and we hit the fallthrough, what would it do then?
}
```

The only possible solution would be to make the `fallthrough` cause the subsequent case expression to leave `i` as an `interface{}`, but that would be a confusing and bad definition.

If you really need this behavior you can already accomplish this with the existing functionality:

```
switch i := x.(type) {
case bool, string:
    if b, ok := i.(bool); ok {
        // b is a bool
    }
    // i is an interface{} that contains either a bool or a string
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, but I must admit I don't really understand why fmt.Printf("%T\n", i) wouldn't print "bool" again. Since in a regular fallthrough the case statement is ignored and the expression is type oblivious. It's probably because I'm relating it to much to a regular switch statement that I've a hard time figuring this one out.

Comment: @Mandarin: Code that compiles if `i` is `string` may not compile if `i` is `bool`. You can't write code that treats one variable as if it has two separate types. So what type would `i` have in the `case bool`? It certainly can't be `bool`, and if it's `string` then you must necessarily discard the value that `i` had in the `case bool`, and without the value your code is pretty useless.

Comment: Actually, it could work if `i` was always an `interface{}`, thus `case bool, string: /* i is an interface{} pointing to either bool or string */` could be the same as `case bool: fallthrough; case string: /* i is an interface{} pointing to either bool or string */`

Comment: @Zippoxer: Except as I said that would be very confusing and it wouldn't be a very useful way to define the language. Just because something technically could be done doesn't make it a good idea.

Comment: Why can we not fallthrough to a `default`? I have a type switch where, if the value is one specific type, it also needs to pass an additional condition to be treated differently than `default`.