# Is there a way to match all interfaces?

Tags: go

When a struct implements multiple interfaces what is the simplest way to match all of them in a function?

The way go's `switch` works the following function is not an option.

```
func f(i interface{}) {
    switch i.(type) {
    case A:
        fmt.Println("A")
    case B:
        fmt.Println("B")
    }
}
```

Even if `i` implements both interfaces `f(i)` outputs only `A`. Adding `fallthrough` [won't help either](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11531335/8208981). So is there a way to check for multiple interfaces?

Comment: You could use embedding `case interface { A; B }:`. https://play.golang.org/p/veyBwDCqyIo

Comment: If you need this, it implies an underlying design problem. What are you trying to do, and why does this code seem necessary?

Comment: @mkopriva and if there are more than 2 interfaces this would require a lot of combinations, right (like some struct implements `A` and `B`, some `A` and `C`, etc.)? Anyways thanks for the tip.

Comment: @Adrian I'm just curious to know how this can be done. I'm also curious to know how it implies an underlying design problem ;-)

Comment: It implies a design problem because there's no normal circumstance where this would be useful.

Comment: Your reply infuriates me @Adrian, because I can completely imagine wanting a differing behavior, if say, you're dealing with a stringable (has a .String() method that returns a string), an error (has a .Error() method that returns a string), or something that is both. I don't see any problems with this use case. I know I'm late, but whatever. To answer the original question, if you can create an interface that is only implemented by types that implement both A and B, you should. That would mean a new interface with the combined method of both.It can also show you if there are incompatibilities

Comment: @AlexSHP the purpose of an interface is polymorphism: I have an interface value X with function Y, I know (and the compiler knows) I can call `X.Y()` regardless of the underlying type. In your example, I have an interface value and I *might* be able to call `String`, or `Error`, or both, but I don't know, so any call I try to make could cause a panic; therefore it offers none of the benefits or use cases of an interface.

Comment: @Adrian, I don't think panics would be an issue if OP managed to make their code segment work. We might want to go from a more general interface to a more generic one. In my example, I was thinking of a formater akin to the one in "fmt", which takes an any{} and tries to divide all types that it might be to assign functionality. I'm not saying it's pretty code. I'm saying that your replies have not provided the answer, just the warnings that should've come with the answer.

Comment: @AlexSHP which is why they're comments, not an answer. If I was providing an answer, I would post it as an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a [type assertion](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions) instead of a `switch` statement to check whether an `interface` variable matches a specific interface. If you want to check multiple interfaces, you can use a sequence of multiple type assertions:

```golang
func f(i interface{}) {
    if _, ok := i.(Aer); ok {
        fmt.Println("A")
    }
    if _, ok := i.(Ber); ok {
        fmt.Println("B")
    }
}
```

(https://play.golang.org/p/6aJxV_j9oqy)

Comment: No. For one, `fallthrough` is not allowed in a type-switch. For two, `fallthrough` executes the next block regardless of whether the case matches (so it would print `"B"` if `i` implements `A` regardless of whether it actually implements `B`). For three, `fallthrough` is linear, so you couldn't use that pattern if more than two types are involved.

Comment: @bcmillls, Thank you for the explanation. Got some knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

It's not at all clear what your purpose is here; as [Adrian notes in comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68727841/is-there-a-way-to-match-all-interfaces#comment121463400_68727841), this isn't something you would normally find in code.

You *might* find something like this in some sort of debug system, where you want to print information about a variable of some interface type to see what interface(s) it implements.  Debuggers generally have direct access to the internal types.  In Go specifically, a debugger could use the `reflect` system here.  `reflect` is deliberately a little bit weaker than debuggers tend to need, but for this particular case, it provides what you might want: you could have a loop that runs through different interface types and invokes `reflect.Type.Implements` on them.

The type assertion in [bcmills' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68727952/1256452) is more efficient but less generalizable: if you're doing your own mini-debugger, you might want to provide a table of potential interface types to a function that prints an interface value.  (If you were building a real debugger, you would not want anything this inefficient, you'd want to reach directly into the type system's guts and read out the raw tables....)